# Declaring TabItems in XAML, binding SelectedItem to view model

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I'd like to bind the `SelectedItem` of a `TabControl` to a corresponding field in my view model, however while still declaring the available items within the `TabControl` itself (as opposed to using `ItemsSource`) and retrieving their `Content` as for the actual `SelectedItem`. Meaning: If a tab is being selected, it's `Content` should end up as the `SelectedItem` (not the `TabItem`) and vice-versa.

Sample view model, inheriting a [Caliburn.Micro conductor](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/blob/49a35e8bac0ee89fd6f983b8a3c63f15b89ac234/src/Caliburn.Micro.Core/Conductor.cs#L10) without (!) collection:

```
public class MyViewModelConductor : Conductor<ConductedViewModelBase> {
  
  public ViewModelA { get; set; }

  public ViewModelB { get; set; }

}
```

And the corresponding `TabControl` in XAML:

```
<TabControl SelectedItem="{Binding ActiveItem}">
  <TabItem cal:View.Model="{Binding ViewModelA}">
    <TabItem.Header> <!-- vm specific fancy UI stuff --> </TabItem.Header>
  </TabItem>
  <TabItem cal:View.Model="{Binding ViewModelB}">
    <TabItem.Header> <!-- vm specific fancy UI stuff --> </TabItem.Header>
  </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

I'm aware I could just use e.g. [`Conductor<'1>.Collection.OneActive`](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/blob/49a35e8bac0ee89fd6f983b8a3c63f15b89ac234/src/Caliburn.Micro.Core/ConductorWithCollectionOneActive.cs#L19) and bind to `ItemsSource`, but there are a few reasons I'd like to refrain from doing so:

- The available view models from the conductor's side is a fixed set, declared by the exposed properties, not an infinite collection
- For the UI's side, for each `TabItem` I need to declare a specific header with lots of just UI related stuff (icon, color) which is platform-specific, hence I would not like to leak it into my view models.

I've tried utilizing `SelectedValue` and `SelectedValuePath` and binding to the TabControl itself (e.g. `SelectedValue="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=SelectedItem}" SelectedValuePath="Content"`), but there WPF tries to look for a `Content` property on my bound view models as soon as one becomes selected.

Comment: When you don't use the ItemsSource to populate the ItemsControl, the ItemsControl will deal with containers only. The SelectedItem, ItemsSource and Items properties for example will hold TabItem controls. You don't want to bind this to your view model classes. Populating the ItemsControl with data models instead will make it easier for you and also help to maintain a clean and mvvm compliant design. Usually you would use DataTemplate for the TabControl.ContentTemplate to template the content and TabControl.ItemTemplate to template the TabItem (TabControl header).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to bind the `SelectedValue` to your view model class. Then use the `SelectedValuePath` to declare which property of the `SelectedItem` is used as the `SelectedValue`.

```xml
<TabControl SelectedValuePath="Content"
            SelectedValue="{Binding ViewModelSelectedContentProperty}">
  <TabItem cal:View.Model="{Binding ViewModelA}">
    <TabItem.Header> <!-- vm specific fancy UI stuff --> </TabItem.Header>
  </TabItem>
  <TabItem cal:View.Model="{Binding ViewModelB}">
    <TabItem.Header> <!-- vm specific fancy UI stuff --> </TabItem.Header>
  </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

But I don't recommend this. You should bind the `ItemSource` to a set of data models and define DataTemplates to give you a clean design and dynamic/extensible behavior.
Usually you would use `DataTemplate` for the `TabControl.ContentTemplate` to template the content and `TabControl.ItemTemplate` to template the `TabItem` (`TabControl` header).

Don't hardcode the `ItemsControl` items. They're is absolutely no reason to avoid data templating.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't thought of binding `SelectedValue`, thanks! The reason to avoid data templating is simplicity. Templating for individual types is easy, but for some of the VMs in my case, I need to re-use the same types (and views), only populated with different data, which then would require me e.g. writing a data template selector, which not only not applies to all items, but would use some not compile-friendly matching, e.g. the title of the VM etc. unless I'd introduce other artificial properties to aid this which weren't needed to begin with. Edge cases sometimes!

Comment: I believe templating makes things easier and more flexible in the end. It's a question of (class) design. Instead of adding identifier properties to a type in order to identify certain variants or configurations, I would suggest to implement a new dedicated class where all classes implement a common interface (to enable polymorphism e.g. to store them in a common container/collection). This way you get rid of template selectors and can make user of implicit templates.